# All Ansible playbook attributes

Tags: ansible

I've just started using Ansible, and after reading the tutorial (which Ansible Team named *"docs"*) I would like to see the full list of all attributes which can be used in playbooks. Is someone able to provide such a list? The only one I was able to Google was [this old example](https://gist.github.com/marktheunissen/2979474) but it lack the things like `gather_facts`.

Maybe someone experienced could paste here a 'skeleton' with the correct structure containing all the atributes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always look into [the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/play.py#L46):

```
# =================================================================================
# Connection-Related Attributes

# TODO: generalize connection
_accelerate          = FieldAttribute(isa='bool', default=False, always_post_validate=True)
_accelerate_ipv6     = FieldAttribute(isa='bool', default=False, always_post_validate=True)
_accelerate_port     = FieldAttribute(isa='int', default=5099, always_post_validate=True)

# Connection
_gather_facts        = FieldAttribute(isa='bool', default=None, always_post_validate=True)
_gather_subset       = FieldAttribute(isa='barelist', default=None, always_post_validate=True)
_gather_timeout      = FieldAttribute(isa='int', default=None, always_post_validate=True)
_hosts               = FieldAttribute(isa='list', required=True, listof=string_types, always_post_validate=True)
_name                = FieldAttribute(isa='string', default='', always_post_validate=True)

# Variable Attributes
_vars_files          = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[], priority=99)
_vars_prompt         = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[], always_post_validate=True)
_vault_password      = FieldAttribute(isa='string', always_post_validate=True)

# Role Attributes
_roles               = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[], priority=90)

# Block (Task) Lists Attributes
_handlers            = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[])
_pre_tasks           = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[])
_post_tasks          = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[])
_tasks               = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[])

# Flag/Setting Attributes
_any_errors_fatal    = FieldAttribute(isa='bool', default=False, always_post_validate=True)
_force_handlers      = FieldAttribute(isa='bool', always_post_validate=True)
_max_fail_percentage = FieldAttribute(isa='percent', always_post_validate=True)
_serial              = FieldAttribute(isa='list', default=[], always_post_validate=True)
_strategy            = FieldAttribute(isa='string', default=C.DEFAULT_STRATEGY, always_post_validate=True)

# =================================================================================
```

Also note that `Play` class inherits `Base`, `Taggable` and `Become`.
So all those classes' attributes are also available to plays.

**Update:**

Here is a Python oneliner suggested by me in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44588726/2795592):

```
python -c 'import ansible.playbook.play as P; print P.Play()._valid_attrs.keys();'
```

Comment: The oneliner fails with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. It is probably python2 and has thus become outdated, right? With contemporary ansible versions `python3 -c 'import ansible.playbook.play as P; print(P.Play()._valid_attrs.keys());'` seem to work.