# Ansible list of possible keys for a play

Tags: key, ansible

Modules each have a quite descriptive documentation on possible keys used there.

Is there anything similar for a play?! I could not find a clear list of possible keys.

What I checked:

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html
- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html

---

Keys I have used already (so they definitely work)

- `name` - though not listed in documentation listed above
- `hosts`
- `remote_user`
- `tasks`
- `pre_tasks`, `post_tasks` - mentioned in a note
- `roles`
- `become`, `become_method`, `become_user`, `become_flags`
- `handlers`, `force_handlers`
- `ignore_errors` - did not find in any listing, but works
- `vars`, `vars_prompt`, `vars_files`
- `gather_facts`, `gather_subset`, `gather_timeout`
- `any_errors_fatal` - not listed
- `accelerate`, `accelerate_ipv6`, `accelerate_port`
- `vault_password`
- `max_fail_percentag`
- `serial`
- `strategy`
- `tags`
- `no_log`
- `connection`
- `ḟact_path`
- `port`
- `environment`
- `check_mode`
- `always_run`
- `run_once`

---

Works but deprecated:

- `sudo`
- `sudo_user`
- `sudo_pass`
- `sudo_exe`
- `sudo_flags`
- `su`
- `su_user`
- `su_pass`
- `su_exe`
- `su_flags`
- `user` - no deprecation warning... ?!

---

Does not seem to work:

- `with_items`, `with_dict`, `loop_control`
- `ǫrder` - though clearly listed in the documentation above
- `when`
- `register`
- `notify`

---

Apparently I did not try all the possibilities (for a length of 20 for example), because that's not a solution for the general question: where should a listing like this be located? Anyone out there having a listing for this?!

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41229018/2846609) discusses parts of the above, although (as eg. `remote_user` is missing from the listing) it is not a reliable listing of parameters IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All Ansible playbook attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228683/all-ansible-playbook-attributes)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov
could be, thanks... although some of the above is not mentioned there (eg.: `remote_user`)

Comment: it is from inherited classes

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov so the answer is: I should plow through the code, and that's it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Directives Glossary](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_keywords.html) seems to list all the keywords I've found to be working. Although it still lists `order` which does not seem to work for me. But whatever, it's still a listing I wished for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shortcut for you:

```
python -c 'import ansible.playbook.play as P; print P.Play()._valid_attrs.keys();'
```

Comment: Thanks. Not a perfect match, but still a better starting point to get a specification than going to the sources on github.